# Neo4j apoc procedures: mysql configuration an use

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, neo4j

I wanted to use the new JDBC procedures from apoc awesome procedures and I faced nany problems.

[First - solved]
I'm not a java developper then "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" was not available on my computer. Download and install Mysql Connector/J. Add to classpath, restart Neo4j, all of this went good.
There was still an error as class "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" couldn't be solved.
I solved by copying the mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar into $NEO4J_PATH/lib but I don't think it's a good practice.

[Second - not solved]
In neo4j, I launched:

```
CALL apoc.load.driver("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
```

No errors.
Then I tried

```
CALL apoc.load.jdbc("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/my_db_name?user=root&password=my_db_password","programmes") YIELD row RETURN count(*);
```

And al I get is this error

```
Failed to call procedure `apoc.load.jdbc(jdbc :: STRING?, tableOrSql :: STRING?) :: (row :: MAP?)`: Cannot execute read result-set.
```

Has anyone faced this problem and solved it?

PS: Sorry for this noob aspect question and for the bad english.
And no my_db_password is not my password ;)

Thanks

Comment: First case is completely solved: I moved mysql-connector-java-5.1.38-bin.jar to $NEO4J_PATH/plugins.

Answer (score 1):

apoc procedures and mysql driver work fine.
THe problem was the volume of retrieved data.
With a WHERE caluse and less results, it works like a charm.

Also, it could be interesting to use neo4j-shell instead of browser for this kind of operation.

Next step: look if batch execution is possible (like the 'WITH row LIMIT' in LOAD CSV)